# php - Insert multiple rows into mysql inserts double rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, text-files

EDIT - I updated the LogsModel.php to give a better picture.

I'm trying to insert data into my table with the values as array items but the data is getting inserted twice. Does anyone know why? When I run the script my database has 8 rows inserted but there's only 4 in the .txt file.

Access2.txt

```
2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
```

**LogsModel.php** (UPDATED)

```
function __construct($db) {
    try {
        $this->db = $db;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit('Database connection could not be established.');
    }
}

public function getAllLogs()
{
    $sql = "SELECT log_date, log_id, log_time FROM log_table";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

public function insertFileContents()
{
    $filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access2.txt';

    // Open the file
    $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');

    // Add each line to an array
    if ($fp) {
        $lines = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

        foreach($lines as $line){
            $l = explode(" ", $line);
            $log_dates = $l[0];
            $log_times = $l[1];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO log_table (log_date, log_time) VALUES ('$log_dates', '$log_times')";

            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
        }

    }

}
```

LogsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    // load a model, perform an action, pass the returned data to a variable
    $logs_model = $this->loadModel('LogsModel');
    $line_items = $logs_model->insertFileContents();
    $logs = $logs_model->getAllLogs();

    // load views.
    require 'application/views/_templates/header.php';
    require 'application/views/home/index.php';
    require 'application/views/_templates/footer.php';
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="container">

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Time</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($logs as $log) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php if (isset($log->log_date)) echo (string)$log->log_date; ?></td>
            <td><?php if (isset($log->log_time)) echo (string)$log->log_time; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

</div>
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `log-data`.`log_table` (
`log_id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`log_date` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`log_time` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `log_id` (`log_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

DB

```
1 2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
2 2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
3 2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
4 2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
5 2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
6 2014-03-25 17:07:00.641
7 2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
8 2014-03-25 17:07:00.672
```

Comment: I see no way the code you posted could do that. Maybe you're calling the function twice, or running your script twice.

Comment: BTW, your `fopen`, `fread`, and `explode` can all be replaced with `file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`.

Comment: I don't see anything that points that your code is being replicated. Why don't you try to set the inserts in a `values(...),(...)` string. This way is faster and can be debugged

Comment: @Barmar - file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) works great, thank you.

Comment: @AlwinKesler - strange, I set the inserts to "one" and "two" and the db table still has 8 rows inserted, but when I display the data in a view there's only 4 rows. It will be a problem down the road when db table rows increase to the 1000's.

Comment: BTW, "UNIQUE KEY `log_id` (`log_id`)" is redundant. It is enough to have "PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)". 
Could you post the IDs so we know the sequence of the insertions.

Comment: what is in your getAllLogs() function?

Comment: @BharatMaheshwari - updated my LogsModel.php to include the getAllLogs() function.

Comment: did you debug the value of $lines in insertFileContents() function?

Comment: @BharatMaheshwari - I even created a new function called "testInsert()" with a simple insert statement and set the inserts to "one" and "two". The output was still duplicated in phpmyadmin...

Comment: The sequence of the IDs indicates that the script or the function is executed twice. It is not that one statement is executed twice each time. It is a code issue.